# Enable TFS 2015 REST API in on-premise installation

Tags: api, rest, tfs, tfs-2015

How can I use or just enable the REST API in an on-premise installation of TFS 2015? I only can find (a lot) information about using API with Visual Studio Online out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the API's are there by default, but not all API's supported by VSO are supported by TFS, especially some of the API's currently under development, may not have shipped with TFS 2015. There is nothing you need to do in addition to "enable" these. They're just there.

Comment: ah ok thank you ... then I've to try on to get the right URL and functions ... :-)

Comment: Unfortunately ours are not just there.  Looks like IIS is missing the folder, and every request to /_apis/ returns a 404 error.